# Support of the convolution of two measures

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $\mu, \nu$ be two Borel Probability measures on a Lie group $G$. I wonder if it is true that

$$supp(\mu \ast \nu)=supp(\mu) \cdot supp(\nu),$$

or at least we have one contained in another?

Recall that the support of a measure is the subset where every neighborhood of each point has positive measure.

Comment: Your definition of "support of a measure" is not correct. One may just take the whole space as a  neighborhood.

Comment: @WhatsUp thanks, just corrected

Comment: Not equality, but the obvious containment, which can indeed be strict. I think if you use a more robust notion of "support" the argument will be easier... Also, this is not about Lie groups, but just topological groups. I've taken the liberty of adding that tag (in a minute).

Comment: @paulgarrett thanks, do you have an example showing the equality fails? (Better for Lie groups)

Comment: Ah, I was not reading carefully. I think if you require non-negative measures you are correct about the support. Without the non-negativity requirement, there are at least silly counter-examples: with $G=\{\pm 1\}$ and $\mu$ the measure that gives $1$ measure $1$ and $-1$ the measure $-1$, and $\nu$ giving both points the measure $+1$, the convolution has value $0$ at $1\in G$...

Comment: @paulgarrett Do you know how to prove the non-obvious direction? I guess it is "$\subset$"?